# How to wait until one of many possible observables returns before continuing

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http

I have switch statement that makes a different http call based on the input.

It looks something like this:

```
switch(myObject.type){
    case 'Type1':
        myObject.name = this.service1.getName(myObject.id);
        break;
    case 'Type2':
        myObject.name = this.service2.getName(myObject.id);
        break;
    case 'Type3':
        myObject.name = this.service3.getName(myObject.id);
        break;
}
```

and immediately after these I have a statement to save the entry:

```
this.storageService.saveEntry(myObject);
```

but at the time the entry is saved, it does not have the name property set.

What is the proper way to wait for any one of these async calls to return before saving the entry?

Comment: make use of `Observable.forkjoin()`

Comment: forkJoin() waits for multiple Observables, here I'm looking for one of many possible Observables.

Comment: @ChrisLang I've updated the answer to utilize RxJS operators to set the value of `myObject.name` as well as pass the value to another observable using `switchMap`. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use the switch statement, you could perhaps have each branch return the observable instead, then set `myObject.name` in the `subscribe()` or utilize operators such as [do](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) and `switchMap` to pass the value to `this.storageService.saveEntry()`.

```
foo(): Observable<any> {
    switch(myObject.type){
        case 'Type1':
            return this.service1.getName(myObject.id);
            break;
        case 'Type2':
            return this.service2.getName(myObject.id);
            break;
        case 'Type3':
            return this.service3.getName(myObject.id);
            break;
    }
}

bar() {    
    foo()
      .do(name => myObject.name = name)
      .switchMap(name => this.storageService.saveEntry(myObject))
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!